# Script of how to add a new row under the new row

Tags: google-apps-script

So basically I have a macro for adding a new row:

```
function Row() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('66:66').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsAfter(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getLastRow(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows(), 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('D74').activate();
```

It adds a row after the last one but whenever I use use the macro again, it adds a new row between instead of under the new one.

Also is there a way that it completely copies the format of the previous row ?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you not just use `spreadsheet.getSheets()[0].appendRow()`?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo No, they need to insert it after a table which is further up the sheet. See the comments of [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63023954/13948276).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This inserts a new row after the last one with content, and copies its formatting.

```
function newRowAfterContent() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.insertRowAfter(sheet.getLastRow());
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).copyFormatToRange(sheet, 1, sheet.getLastColumn(), sheet.getLastRow() + 1, sheet.getLastRow() + 1);
}
```

For your case with the tables:

```
function newRowAfterNamedRange() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var namedRangeObj = sheet.getNamedRanges()
    .find((range) => range.getName() == "MyRange");
  var namedRange = namedRangeObj.getRange();
  sheet.insertRowAfter(namedRange.getRow() + namedRange.getHeight() - 1);
  sheet.getRange(namedRange.getRow() + namedRange.getHeight() - 1, namedRange.getColumn(), 1, namedRange.getWidth()).copyFormatToRange(sheet, namedRange.getColumn(), namedRange.getColumn() + namedRange.getWidth() - 1, namedRange.getRow() + namedRange.getHeight(), namedRange.getRow() + namedRange.getHeight());
  namedRangeObj.setRange(sheet.getRange(namedRange.getRow(), namedRange.getColumn(), namedRange.getHeight() + 1, namedRange.getWidth()));
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it adds a new row after the last row of the second table that ends at row 78, but I have a table a few rows on top where the new row should add. That table ends at row 66.

Comment: You could try using seperate sheets (tabs) for each table - that would make the data easier to deal with. The other option would be to name a range as being the table you want.

Comment: I know how to name a range, but what do I add to the script then ?

Comment: If you're going to use named ranges, you'll need to get a list of named ranges in the sheet, pick the first one, append a row at the end of it, add the formatting, and then expand the named range to include the new row. I'm working on an example now.

Comment: Where is it ?
Can't find it :)

Comment: `function newRowAfterNamedRange() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var namedRange = sheet.getNamedRanges()[0].getRange();
  sheet.insertRowAfter(namedRange.getRow() + namedRange.getHeight() - 1);
  sheet.getRange(namedRange.getRow() + namedRange.getHeight() - 1, namedRange.getColumn(), 1, namedRange.getWidth()).copyFormatToRange(sheet, namedRange.getColumn(), namedRange.getColumn() + namedRange.getWidth() - 1, namedRange.getRow() + namedRange.getHeight(), namedRange.getRow() + namedRange.getHeight());`

Comment: `
  sheet.getNamedRanges()[0].setRange(sheet.getRange(namedRange.getRow(), namedRange.getColumn(), namedRange.getHeight() + 1, namedRange.getWidth()));
}`

Comment: Where do I add the name of the range ?

Comment: Sorry; computer died. The program I've written selects the _first_ named range. To select a particular range, replace `var namedRange = sheet.get....` with `var namedRange, namedRangeObj;
sheet.getNamedRanges().forEach((range)=>{if (range.getName() == "INSERT NAME HERE") {namedRange = range.getRange();namedRangeObj=range;}});` and on the last row, replace `sheet.getNamedRanges()[0]` with `namedRangeObj.setR....`.